# What would cause php's strtotime to not work for a date in 2099?

Tags: php

I have three servers, doing the following on all three servers:

```
echo strtotime('2099-12-31');
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
```

gets me:

Server #1: (php 5.3.8, 64bit)

```
4102376400
1328418000
```

Server 2: (php 5.3.2, 32bit)

```
**[nothing]**
1328418000
```

Server #3: (php 5.3.2 - 64bit I thought it might be a php version issue)

```
4102376400
1328418000
```

What would cause strtotime to fail on one of the servers but not the others?  All three have the same Default timezone and date.timezone settings in php.ini (not sure if that would have an effect or not).  I also turned on errors and I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: Well, at a guess that date is large enough to be outside the 32 bit unix epoch (any date 2038 or later). Could it be a 32 bit vs 64 bit thing?

Comment: one of your servers takes in to account the Mayan prophecy.

Comment: Consider using a [DateTime instance](http://php.net/datetime) here instead of trying to represent an epoch timestamp.  DateTime can represent dates beyond the 32-bit limit of the epoch, regardless of platform.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably it is a 32-bit issue. It works just fine on my 64-Bit Server, but my 32-bit Ubuntu returns false on `strtotime('2099-12-31')`

For further information see this note in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (highlighting by me):

> **The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)** Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.
>
> For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range of a timestamp is effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293 billion years in either direction.

Comment: The PHP manual is so silly. There is a **big** difference between 293 billion and infinity.

Comment: That's where "effectively" comes in.

Comment: The only effect it has is to make me cringe and write these comments.

Comment: How can something be effectively infinite? It either is or it isn't.

Comment: Oh look: `date('l jS F, Y', strtotime('+300000000000 years'));` evaluates to `Unknown 30th March, -284554047242`. Not effectively infinite, then!

Answer (score 2):

As per the [docs](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.) Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.
>
> For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range of a timestamp is effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293 billion years in either direction.

Try e.g `2019-12-31`, should work as expected.