# when using strtotime function with the year 2099 not working in Laravel

Tags: php, strtotime

I have the code

```
<?php echo strtotime( '2099-12-31' ); ?>
```

Is written on the Laravel Framework, when running the program it does not produce results, but when I run on the folder I manually create it completely run the output. For smaller values, eg

```
<?php echo strtotime( '2017-12-31' ); ?>
```

in Laravel running completely normal .Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would cause php's strtotime to not work for a date in 2099?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153014/what-would-cause-phps-strtotime-to-not-work-for-a-date-in-2099)

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are using Laravel or not, it is still a php function and Laravel doesn't change that. Where are you putting this line in your Laravel project?

Comment: I test in the model, controller, view . Not working

Comment: @BaTrần Please, consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953378/3903412) to the question [Maximum time() | PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953333/maximum-time-php)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe that is 32-bit server issue, max date is about 2038. check your server enviroment